# EAR lib's class throwing a ClassNotFoundException for a WAR member

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I packaged an EAR (myear.ear) file and deployed it in JBoss EAP 6 (that is, JBoss 7 :)). 
It looks like this:

```
lib/ 
  my-common.jar (Custom library containing common classes used by both the WAR and BIZ)
  --- (other libraries used by both WAR and BIZ) ---
META-INF/
    jboss-deployment-structure.xml (specifies just <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated> )
my-biz.jar (EJB Module)
    META-INF/
        beans.xml
        MANIFEST.MF
    -- java classes -- 
my-war.war (WAR Module)
    WEB-INF/
        beans.xml
        lib/ (empty! I made a skinny war)
    META-INF/
        MANIFEST.MF
    resources/
    -- java classes --
```

In `my-war.war` there is a class which calls a method from a class from `my-common.jar`. Here is what happens:

```
public class MyWarMember implements Serializable{//my-war.war

  public void foo(){
    MyCommonMember.deepCopy(this);
  }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyCommonMember{//my-common.jar
  public static Object deepCopy(Serializable obj){

    ObjectOutputStream oos .....
    ...
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    ....
    ObjectInputStream ois ....;
    ....
    ois.readObject(); 
  }
}
```

The call to `ois.readObject();` will throw a ClassNotFoundException for MyWarMember:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.war.MyWarMember from [Module "deployment.myear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

How would you solve this? Thanks!

Comment: There is a bit of confusion in the code you list, the `MyWarMember` method `foo` calls `MyCommonClass.deepCopy`, but the lines below show that `deepCopy` is a method of the `MyCommonMember` class. Moreover you say that the call to `ois.readObject`, which occurs in `MyCommonMember.deepCopy`, throws a `ClassNotFoundException` for `MyWarMember`, that seems to be in the same package. Can you explain better where is the problem?

Comment: @remigio you're right I was too fast.. I updated the question, hope now it is clear..

Comment: Is there any library your `my-common.jar` requires to use?

Comment: I dont't understand how a call to `ObjectInputStream.readObject` could throw an exception about the `MyWarMember` class, maybe you assign the result to an object of that class?

Comment: @Quincy yes, my-common.jar has several dependencies to external libraries

Comment: Have you noticed that the ClassNotFoundException is talking about my.war.MywarMeber (Meber not Member!!!). I don't know if it's that you have just missspelled the error, or if it's really the cause of the problem.

Comment: @ToniS.Magraner unfortunately that was just a typo.. :)

Comment: @Federico Can you show more context?

Answer (score 1):

You have created a cyclic dependency between your `my-war.war` and your common jar `my-common.jar`.

1. From `MyWarMember` you are invoking

   `MyCommonMember.deepCopy(this);` - This will work, since you have added the jar in your lib
2. From `MyCommomMember` you are doing

   `public static Object deepCopy(Serializable obj){` - Class not found exception because it doesn't know about your `MyWarMember` which is in `my-war.war`.

**Solution:**
Remove your cyclic dependency.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a problem of multiple isolated classloaders. From the exception, it complains that the problematic place is `deployment.myear.ear:main` that does not see `MyWarMember`. This could be, as war module is not in EAR's lib folder.

Note: there is indirect cyclic dependency, `my-war.war` uses `my-common.jar` which processes untyped class from `my-war.war` but for sake of serialization it need to know the actual type.