# EAR lib's class throwing a ClassNotFoundException for a WAR member (different)

Tags: java, jar, glassfish, war, ear

My EAR has the following structure :

```
lib/ 
  helper.jar (Helper classes used both by war1.war and war2.war)
war1.war
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
            entities1.jar
war2.war
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
            entities2.jar
```

When war1 calls a class in helper.jar that itself calls Class.forName("a class in war1"), it throws a **ClassNotFoundException**.

Notice that people usually have ClassNotFoundException when a war class loads a ear/lib class. **My case is the reverse situation.**

My EAR is deployed in Glassfish 3.1.2.

I've seen a similar case, but in JBoss, "[EAR lib's class throwing a ClassNotFoundException for a WAR member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387250/ear-libs-class-throwing-a-classnotfoundexception-for-a-war-member)", but the answers say it's a "cyclic dependency" problem. However, I don't see any "cyclic dependency" problem here. In java, any ClassX can refer to ClassY even if ClassY refers to ClassX....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `helper.jar` you can't simply load a class situated in your `war1.war` using `Class.forName`.

The limitation comes from the default classloader used by the  `Class.forName` method, which is the enterprise app's classloader (the one which loads `helper.jar`), which knows only its parents, not its children (`war1.war` and `war2.war` classloaders).

The solution for your problem is to use explicitely the **context** classloader, which scans in order:

war -> ear -> system -> extension -> bootstrap

This can be done using:

```
Class.forName("war1Class.class",true,Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
```